# C# DataGridView Removing Data Rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This may be quite a common asked question with regards to the search results, however, I haven't yet found the answer to my problem.

I am loading 3 different types of DataGridView's in 3 different Pages (Window forms), and in each and every single one of them, previously viewed data rows are added onto it (the newly opened DataGridView).

Does anyone know of a way I can prevent this from happening?

```
 private void Emp_Awaiting_Dispatch_Orders_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TBL_Order ord in DataLOrders.Get_Status_AwaitingDispatchOrder())
        {
            ViewAwaitDipOrd_DGV.Rows.Add(ord.OrderID, ord.CustomerID, ord.ProductID, ord.Status, ord.Quantity, "Switch to Dispatched");
        }
    }
    private void ViewAwaitDipOrd_DGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewAwaitDipOrd_DGV.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
            {
                BusinessLOrders.OrderDispatched();

                foreach (TBL_Order ord in DataLOrders.Get_Status_AwaitingDispatchOrder())
                {                 
                    Int32.TryParse(ViewAwaitDipOrd_DGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), out cellID);

                    if (ord.ProductID == cellID)
                    {
                        Int32.TryParse(ViewAwaitDipOrd_DGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), out cellID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a bool column - which can be invisible - to the datasource and use a RowFilter to filter them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check for row count

```
dataGridView.Rows.Count
```

and if there are existing rows you can clear them

```
dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
```

Make sure you add header row first if it is not automatically added by source.
Hope it helps